# mv file.sh /location where the file.sh gone?

Tags: linux, mv

So in my archlinux set up, when I was tired I accidentally typed...

`mv file.sh /location`

instead of...

`mv file.sh location/`

So I was wondering where that file has gone? and can I get it back?

I have already tried `find / -name /location` but as it thinks its a directory is wont even try and find the file, Have I permanently lost that file now? If so I will never use my terminal when tired again lmao!

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /location`?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 644 Nov 15 02:53 /location` I also already had a directory called location, don't know if that would do anything.

Comment: @ConnorAllsopp Your  file `file.sh` actually has been renamed to `location` and this one is placed on the root directory `/`. Just use `mv /location /home/user/file.sh`

Comment: Huh so it is, thanks I'm annoyed that I didn't think of that, after you said it I was like of course it's in the root directory, thank again